# Load data from MongoDB to HashMap

Tags: java, mongodb, dictionary, hashmap, mongo-java

i am wondering how can i do to load a HashMap from MongoDB using Java, this is a project of mine for Minecraft & Bukkit. I have saved the data like the following:

```
private Map<String, String> petNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and i am saving it like this:

```
representation.put("PetNames", petNames);
```

But i dont know how to actually after the user joins back again add all the data from "PetNames" to the petNames Map.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just cast it

```
petNames=(Map)yourDBCollection.findOne();
```